# Invalid ELF header caused by bcrypt

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor

I followed this solution:

[bcrypt is breaking my meteor application, how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340510/bcrypt-is-breaking-my-meteor-application-how-do-i-fix-it)

But Im still getting this error:

```
    /home/kaleobox/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                                                    throw(ex);
                                                          ^
    Error: /home/kaleobox/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at bindings (/home/kaleobox/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:74:15)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kaleobox/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I went into `/home/kaleobox/bundle/programs/server/node_modules` and did:

`rm -R /home/kaleobox/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/bcrypt`

then

`npm install bcrypt`

but the error above persists.  The line

`/home/kaleobox/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header`

tells me I may have to remove and reinstall bcrypt in that second location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should reinstall bcrypt from

> /home/kaleobox/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node-modules

instead of

> /home/kaleobox/bundle/programs/server/node_modules

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because it can be difficult for the original poster (or future readers) to understand the logic behind them. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!

Comment: How does one use your suggestion through npm?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by re-installing the bcrypt package in the below directory:

- Access to this directory:

  `/my_app/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/`
- Then run `npm install bcrypt`
- Start your app again. It should be fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

As @lingxiao-sun's answer indicates, you *may* find that copying the `bcrypt` in `/home/kaleobox/bundle/programs/server/node_modules` into `/home/kaleobox/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node-modules` will fix this issue.

This is possibly because the `bcrypt` in `<your project>/bundle/programs/server/node_modules` will have been built/installed locally to the host machine, whereas the `bcrypt` in `/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node-modules/` will likely be from a source/build machine, and if these environments differ it can cause issues due to  the specific binaries required for each environment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you committed your bcrypt executable which was in Windows architecture, but Heroku virtual environments are Linux.

Add `node_modules` to your `.gitignore` and use `git rm -r --cached node_modules`.

The command will remove `node_modules` from your Git repository and, in your next push, changes to `node_modules` will be ignored.